# Switching between ViewControllers without recreating them

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uicontainerview

At current moment, i'm using ***ContainerView*** approach, where is going switch between **ViewControllers** like that:

```
  FromViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(null); 

    ToViewController.View.Frame = SourceViewController.View.Bounds;

    SourceViewController.AddChildViewController(ToViewController);

SourceViewController.Tansition(FromViewController,ToViewController,
0.5,UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,() => {} ,(bool IsFinished) =>
{
   FromViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
   ToViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(SourceViewController);

});
```

All work's fine, except one **thing** : anytime when i'm switching between  them(ViewControllers),they recreates from ***zero***.

And now i want to do the same stuff, but without re-creation of each VC that is switched at current moment.

---

### Questions :

1. I don't want to recreate **VC** each time, when switch is doing job. Somehow to make an overlay of **VC** on another one and vice versa or maybe it should be hided!? Is this a good approach to achieve my goal?
2. What about memory usage of this approach? For e.g. : if i will have several **VC's** (like 4-5 quantity). Is this fine to make it or anyway i need to destroy them and recreate from zero?

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign the 2 view controllers to variables of the class. You can lazy load them so they won't get created every time you access them.
2. It's totally fine, in fact this is how the UITabBarViewController behaves.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. CAn you provide an example with container view and lazy load?